# I cannot import a csv into pgadmin4 because PERMISSION DENIED

Tags: postgresql, pgadmin

I am trying to import a .csv from my desktop into pgadmin but I get an error, and I'm not sure how to fix it. Here is my syntax:

```
COPY nypennss(name, grade, avg, h, average, team, size)
FROM '/Users/computer/Downloads/computer/SS_nyp'
DELIMITER ','
CSV HEADER;
```

And here is the output:

> ERROR:  could not open file "/Users/computes/Downloads/computer/SS_nyp" for reading: Permission denied
>
> HINT:  COPY FROM instructs the PostgreSQL server process to read a file.
>
> You may want a client-side facility such as psql's \copy.
> SQL state: 42501

I have been trying to grant access to the file but it's not seeming to work. I also used \copy.

Does anybody have any suggestions? Also, I am on a mac- thanks

Comment: Is your server on the Mac as well

Comment: Yes, my server is on the mac as well.

Comment: The file needs to be accessible by the user the server runs as. Can u check that, that’s the case

Comment: I tried to grant access to the postgres, and my user with the option to “read and write”. But after I did that I was still not able to import the file